Reism and its proponents
Do you know some contemporary philosophers who believe in Reism or Concretism, especially the idealistic version of it?
A reist is a person who doesn't believe in

Properties
states of affairs (relations)
sets (abstract sets)
universals

and believe that everything is not 1 or 2 or 3 or 4.
I consider myself a reist and I would be very happy to know that there are individuals who share the same line of thought as me.

Do you know the modern proponents of it, like Kotarbinski?

OF course, I knew that I was a Reist when I read by chance of his papers. I'm just asking for contemporary names, Philosophers that are active and still alive.  The literature on the subject is very poor, and I think it's a shame that such an interesting position doesn't get the interest that it deserves.

Yes, but The term "nominalism" could be used to describe a position that  denies universals. for example, a person who denies universals and believes in tropes could be considered a nominalist. Reism is the extreme version of nominalism, it highlights the fact that names that talk about properties, relations, sets, and universals are apparent not true names.
